# Scala - head of empty list - removing all None's from a list of Options

Tags: scala

Been trying to solve this for a while now. I need a recursive function that removes all None's from a list of Option[Int]'s, without using if-statements or using other functions.

```
def RemoveNone2(input: List[Option[Int]]) : List[Int] = {
  input.head match {
    case None => RemoveNone2(input.tail)
    case _ => (input.head.get::RemoveNone2(input.tail))
  }
}

val optional: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(13), None, Some(32), None, Some(51), None, Some(17), None)
RemoveNone2(optional)
```

But when trying to execute the code, I get the following error:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: head of empty list
```

I suck at Scala, could anyone offer some insight?

Comment: try to think about your solution if `input` has not head and empty. What should `input.head` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `headOption`:

```
def RemoveNone2(input: List[Option[Int]]) : List[Int] = input.headOption match {
    case None => RemoveNone2(input.tail)
    case Some(head) => head :: RemoveNone2(input.tail)
}
```

A better way to write this is:

```
def removeNone(input: List[Option[Int]]) : List[Int] = input match {
   case Nil => Nil
   case Some(head) :: tail => head :: removeNone(tail)
   case None :: tail => removeNone(tail)
```

An even better way is to use an accumulator, so that you can take advantage of tail-recursion:

```
def removeNone(input: List[Option[Int]], out: List[Int]=Nil) : List[Int] = input match {
   case Nil => out.reverse
   case Some(head) :: tail => removeNone(tail, head :: out)
   case None :: tail => removeNone(tail, out)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that input list is empty to break the recursion. One of the options is to [match against the list itself](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-lists-nil-cons-scala-match-case-expressions/):

```scala
def RemoveNone2(input: List[Option[Int]]) : List[Int] = input match {
  case head :: tail => head match {
    case Some(value) => value :: RemoveNone2(tail)
    case _ => RemoveNone2(tail)
  }
  case _ => Nil
}
```

Also note, that this implementation is not [tail-recursive](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/fp-book/tail-recursive-algorithms/), whcih can lead to errors or poor performance for big collections. Tail-recursive implementation can look like that:

```scala
def RemoveNone2(input: List[Option[Int]]) : List[Int] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def inner(innerInput: List[Option[Int]], acc: List[Int]): List[Int] = innerInput match {
    case head :: tail => head match {
      case Some(value) => inner(tail, value::acc)
      case _ => inner(tail, acc)
    }
    case _ => acc
  }   
  inner(input, Nil)
}
```